# How to consume Azure devops REST API in angular

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, msal-angular

I have created an Angular application where I have to use Azure DevOps REST API to retrieve ticket  details. I'm authenticating user against clients Azure-AD using `@azure/msal-angular", "@azure/msal-browser"`  packages.

I'm using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) which says this the syntax for the URL should be something like  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}` which did not work for me

But when I paste `GET https://[ClientURL.com]/[resource/location]/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=123`  into browser address bar I get JSON response.

I'm using the token I get to consume REST services by calling my clients url something like this
`GET https://[ClientURL.com]/[resource/location]/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=123`

I'm intercepting the requests using `MsalInterceptor` which will add the Authentication header.

I get an error saying **`Interceptor - acquireTokenSilent rejected with error. Invoking interaction to resolve.`**

I couldn't find any good enough documents for angular and having trouble understanding whether I have to authenticate again for REST API's or the AD authentication should just be fine.

**UPDATE**

The application was already built using C#. My client wants it to be developed using Angular.
This is my login configuration

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
        return new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {
                clientId: '' // my registered angular app clientId,
                authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenentid',
                redirectUri: 'https://localhost:8080',
                
            },
            cache: {
              cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
            }
        })
        }
```

I'm using MSAL to authenticate my app

```
loginMsal() {
  this.msalService.loginPopup().subscribe(
    (response: AuthenticationResult) => {
      this.loginSuccessfull(response)

    })
 }
```

Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the [application you registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#create-the-app-registration) in azure portal has been granted permissions for Azure DevOps. See below steps to grant permissions for Azure DevOps.

Navigate to the registered application portal-->**API permissions** under **Manage**-->Add a permission-->select **Azure DevOps**-->select **Delegated Permissions**-->check `user_impersonation`.

And you can add the access token you get in the Authentication header like below example from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/d71af3176f1c560a010cac9062b459aeee742554/JavascriptWebAppSample/index.html#L74).

```
var vstsApi = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.1-preview.3"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                
xhr.open('GET', vstsApi, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
```

See the [Javascript Web App Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/JavascriptWebAppSample#javascript-web-app-sample) for more information.

Update:

```
const tokenRequest = {
      scopes: [ "api://499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default" ]
 };

this.authService.instance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest).then(tokenResponse => {
              
              var vstsApi = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproje/_apis/wit/workitems/5?api-version=6.1-preview.3"
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                
              xhr.open('GET', vstsApi, true);
              var res = xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken);
 })
```

Comment: I get the following error even though i have "user_impersonation" permission
"TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

Comment: @KedarUdupa Could you share the relevant part of your code to get the access token? The  access token should be generated for `azure devops` resource(ie. `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 or https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com`).

Comment: I have updated my question. Also is it necessary to authenticate to both the resources separately.!? I'm just learning Azure and would really appreciate your help

Comment: @KedarUdupa You can check the document [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md) to acquire an access token for Azure devops api. See above update: